# How to generate jVectorMap for United Kingdom (UK)?

Tags: python, united-kingdom, jvectormap

I have shapefile for UK , i need to convert this to the jVectorMap
Here is my script

```
python ^
   converter.py ^
   ./shapefile/map.shp ^
   ./output/jquery-uk.js ^
   --width 400 ^
   --where "ISO = 'GBR'" ^
   --language en ^
   --country_name_index ? ^
   --country_code_index ? ^
   --minimal_area 40000 ^
   --buffer_distance -0.5 ^
   --simplify_tolerance 10000 ^
   --longitude0 ? ^
   --name UK
```

how to find the values(?) country_name_index, country_code_index and longitude0?

I have referred the following pages,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068645/how-to-generate-a-new-map-for-jvectormap-jquery-plugin

http://jvectormap.com/documentation/gis-converter/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate jVector map for UK](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90637/how-to-generate-jvector-map-for-uk) - rather than asking a near identical Question again, I recommend that you consider editing your original one to make what you have already tried clearer.

Comment: @PolyGeo i don't know how to find country_name_index, country_code_index and longitude in order to generate map for UK. when i tried some values say., 12,13 and 54.33 i got an inappropriate map output.

Comment: Have you looked in its Help?  If so, to show us that you have not chosen asking here as your first step, it would be useful to include a link to the help pages describing what you are trying to do.

Comment: @PolyGeo i have added the links where i referred.

Comment: As stated in the documentation you can use tools like `ogrinfo`(http://www.gdal.org/ogrinfo.html) to help you find out the specifics of your shape file. Or provide a link to your shapefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found the values of  **--country_name_index** and **--country_code_index** with the help of QGIS Browser,

[image: Qgis Browser]

Opened the shapefile using QGis Browser and then in the "Attributes" section the following things are found.
It is based on zero indexed.

--country_name_index 6

--country_name_index 5

for --longitude0 -3.7(googled it)
That's it! I got the output.

Thanks everyone

Comment: For this to qualify as an Answer that I could upvote, I think you should describe in more detail how precisely QGIS Browser helped you find those values, and what values you found.

Comment: Answer updated. @PolyGeo.